# Why am I getting extra index values when multi-mapping words to lines from text file C++?

Tags: c++, indexing, multimap

I am working on a multimap program that takes in a text file, removes puncuation, and then creates an index of each word in relation to what line it appears on. The code compiles and runs, but I am getting output that I don't want. I'm pretty sure the problem is dealing with punctuation. Everytime the word is followed by a period character it counts that word twice, even though I am excluding puncuation. Then it prints the final word out several times, saying it exists on lines that do not exist in the file. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Input File:

```
dogs run fast.
dogs bark loud.
cats sleep hard.
cats are not dogs.
Thank you.
#
```

C++ Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    ifstream input;
    input.open("NewFile.txt");
    if ( !input )
    {
        cout << "Error opening file." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    multimap< string, int, less<string> >  words;
    int line; //int variable line
    string word;//string variable word

    // For each line of text, the length of input, increment line
    for (line = 1; input; line++)
    {
        char buf[ 255 ];//create a character with space of 255
        input.getline( buf, 128 );//buf is pointer to array of chars where
        //extracted, 128 is maximum num of chars to write to s.

        // Discard all punctuation characters, leaving only words
        for ( char *p = buf;
              *p != '\0';
              p++ )

        {
            if ( ispunct( *p ) )
                *p = ' ';
        }
        //

        istringstream i( buf );

        while ( i )
        {
            i >> word;
            if ( word != "" )
            {
                words.insert( pair<const string,int>( word, line ) );
            }
        }
    }

    input.close();

    // Output results
    multimap< string, int, less<string> >::iterator it1;
    multimap< string, int, less<string> >::iterator it2;



    for ( it1 = words.begin(); it1 != words.end(); )
    {

        it2 = words.upper_bound( (*it1).first );
        cout << (*it1).first << " : ";

        for ( ; it1 != it2; it1++ )
        {
            cout << (*it1).second << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Thank : 5
are : 4
bark : 2
cats : 3 4
dogs : 1 2 4 4
fast : 1 1
hard : 3 3
loud : 2 2
not : 4
run : 1
sleep : 3
you : 5 5 6 7
```

Desired Output:

```
Thank : 5
are : 4
bark : 2
cats : 3 4
dogs : 1 2 4 
fast : 1 
hard : 3 
loud : 2 
not : 4
run : 1
sleep : 3
you : 5
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: And when you step through this in your debugger what do you see?

Comment: @RichardCritten Ah! For some reason it is adding an extra count to the mapping at the end of the sentence. It's doing an extra line 44 `words.insert( pair<const string,int>( word, line ) );` Why is it doing this? Shouldn't it be stopping because the punctuation has been removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not removing the punctuation, you are replacing with spaces. `istringstream` tries to parse those spaces but if fails. You should check if parsing a word is successful or not doing this way:

```
i >> word;
if (!i.fail()) {
    words.insert(pair<const string, int>(word, line));
}
```

Since you are using C++, it would be more convenient to avoid using pointer, rather focus on using std functions. I would rewrite a part of your code like this:

```
// For each line of text, the length of input, increment line
for (line = 1; !input.eof(); line++)
{
    std::string buf;
    std::getline(input, buf);

    istringstream i( buf );

    while ( i )
    {
        i >> word;
        if (!i.fail()) {
            std::string cleanWord;
            std::remove_copy_if(word.begin(), word.end(),
                                std::back_inserter(cleanWord),
                                std::ptr_fun<int, int>(&std::ispunct)
            );
            if (!cleanWord.empty()) {
                words.insert(pair<const string, int>(cleanWord, line));
            }
        }
    }
}

input.close();

// Output results
multimap< string, int, less<string> >::iterator it1;
multimap< string, int, less<string> >::iterator it2;
```